# Create drill down view in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to create an emberjs application and am having trouble coming up with the best approach to create the ui i would like.  I want to have an application with a drill down selection component, and when at a certain level, allow the user to select an item and add it to their bucket/cart.  The high level idea is having itemGroups at the top level, and then items in each item group(2 levels will suffice for now).

I have the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFkBB/2/) that gives a simple example.  In this example i have my groups, and then below that my bucket.  What i would like to do is when i click on a group update that portion of the view to show the items in that group.

Once i have that ultimately i would like to allow the user to select those items and add to their bucket.  Essentially the user can traverse the group/item hierarchy to select items to add to their bucket.

I am sure i am over complicating this but am not sure exactly how to proceed with this.

HTML

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <h1> ember - latest jsfiddle </h1>
  {{itemGroup}}
  <br>
  <br>
  {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h2> Bucket Items: </h2>
  <div>{{model}}</div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="itemGroup">
  <h2> Groups </h2>
  {{#each ig in controllers.itemGroup }}
    <div class="buttonlink">{{ig}}</div > 
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

JS

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: "itemGroup",
  itemGroup: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.itemGroup")
});
App.ItemGroupController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
App.ItemGroupView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'itemGroup',
  click:function(){
  alert('i should replace the item group view with item details');
  return false;
}  
});
Ember.Handlebars.helper('itemGroup', App.ItemGroupView);

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function () {
    return "my bucket"
},
setupController: function (controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.controllerFor('itemGroup').set('model', ['group a', 'group b', 'group c',     'group d']);
}
});
```

**Update**

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EsXPm/2/) i have update my original example based on some of the things found through choppers comments.  I want to just update the groups section with the items in the group, and leave the bucket section, my routes will be based on the bucket to load the current state of the bucket, and then allow the user to drill through the groups/items, the latest update shows more what i am thinking.

I can get it to work, i'm not sure if this is the 'ember' way of doing this type of interaction or if there is a more idiomatic way.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I have something that is working based on my the last fiddle i posted(http://jsfiddle.net/EsXPm/2/), it works although i'm not sure it's the 'ember' way to do this.  I'm going to iterate on it more over the weekend, i'll post what i come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Note: Apologies for the lengthy answer, but I thought it would be good to elaborate, since this is quite a common use case and this should be helpful to anyone new to Ember (and Ember Data).

In my opinion the following would be the best way to implement your scenario in Ember and Ember Data:

Set up your templates for the `application` (everything else will be rendered into this routes's `{{outlet}}`), `groups` (this template will wrap everything to do with groups), `groups/index` (to display a list of all groups) and `group` (to display one group).

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1> ember - latest jsfiddle </h1>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="groups">
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="groups/index">
    <h2> Groups </h2>
   {{#each group in content }}
    <div class="buttonlink">
        {{#link-to "group" group}}{{group.name}}{{/link-to}}</div>
    </div >
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="group">
    <h2>{{name}} Items</h2>
   {{#each item in items}}
    <div class="buttonlink">
        {{item.name}}</div>
    </div >
    {{/each}}
    <br />
    {{#link-to "groups.index"}}Back to groups{{/link-to}}
</script>
```

In your JS you then set up your store. For testing I used the `DS.FixturesAdapter`, which lets me specify data directly in my JS for testing purposes. Eventually you will want to replace this with something like `DS.RESTAdapter` to talk to your backend.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 13,
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});
```

We then specify our models using Ember Data:

```
App.Group = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    items: DS.hasMany('item', { async: true }),
});

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    group: DS.belongsTo('group'),
});
```

I omitted the fixtures data for brevity's sake, but you can see it in the jsFiddle below. The `{ async: true }` tells Ember Data that the parent (App.Group) and child (App.Item) models are asynchronously loaded (i.e. not necessarily at the same time).

As a next step we define which routes we have in our application. For this example we only care about groups - specifically looking all groups and at individual ones.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('groups', function() {
        this.resource('group', { path: '/group/:group_id' });
    });
});
```

Now all that remains to be done is to tell Ember what to do when each route is entered:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('groups.index');
    }
});
```

The `App.Index` route is the default route of the application (think of it as the 'home' route). In our case we want to go directly to a list of groups, so we redirect to `groups.index`.

```
App.GroupsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.get('store').findAll('group');
    }
});
```

This sets the model of the route to all groups that we have in our store. Ember will automatically detect that this is an array and create a corresponding `Ember.ArrayController` that we can use in that route - but we could also override it if we wanted to add additional functionality.

Note that we do not need to explicitly set up an `App.GroupRoute` or `App.GroupIndexRoute` since Ember is smart enough to do that for us in the background (however, again, we could override it if we needed to).

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFkBB/7/).

Comment: thanks for the great detailed example chopper, see the update to my original question(and new fiddle) i think i am getting closer thanks to your help, i'm just not sure if the way i have it working is the best way.

Comment: @broschb, I'm not sure I fully understand what you are after. Is your 'bucket' like a shopping basket that you want to add items (from the different groups) to? How should the bucket be displayed?

Comment: yes, that is a good way to think about it, i have a larger example, i'll convert to a jsbin that does more in the routes and has some models, i'll convert it to a jsbin later and post it, thanks again for your help.

Comment: here is another fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8t5Bd/33/, hopefully it shows more the flow i am thinking.  At a high level a user selects a bucket/cart, the next route shows the contents of the bucket/cart, and allows the user to edit contents(add, delete) so far i'm just working on adding.  I would like my routes to reflect the current state of the bucket/cart and just show the avail groups, it's fine if they always refresh to the root level of the drill down.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this depends on your use case. One way would be to load the items in your template but hide them and then toggle their visibility using jQuery.

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="itemGroups">
    <h2> Groups </h2>
   {{#each ig in controllers.itemGroup }}
       {{itemGroup}}
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="itemGroup">
    <div class="buttonlink">
        <div class="group">{{ig.name}}</div>
        <div class="details hidden">{{ig.items}}</div>        
    </div >
</script>
```

View:

```
App.ItemGroupView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'itemGroup',
    click:function(){
        this.$('.details, .group').toggleClass('hidden');
        return false;
  }  
});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Have a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFkBB/4/).

Comment: Thanks, that is along the lines of what i am looking for, the only difference is i would like to replace the whole items group view with the contents of the item, instead of just the one element.  I'm working on trying to modify the fiddle to do that, and will post once if i get anything working.

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the list of groups with a list of items in the selected group? Are you using Ember Data?

Comment: yes, i want to replace the list of groups with the list of items in the selected group, I will be using emberdata, i haven't gotten that far yet, still trying to figure out the basics.